# Apache2.2 Url whitelisting from basic auth

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a virtualhost configured with basic auth, but I want to whitelist only one url, because it will be called from a 3rd party API where I can't configure authentication. I read the other questions here but I couldn't get it work, this is how it looks like now:

```
<Location "^/this/url">
       AuthType None
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all
       Satisfy any
</Location>
<Location />
        AuthUserFile "/srv/.htpasswd"
        AuthName authorization
        AuthType Basic
        require valid-user

       Order Allow,Deny
       Deny from all
       Satisfy any
</Location>
```

So I want `http://www.example.com` to have authentication but `http://www.example.com/this/url` don't.